# Install Ubuntu on a second internal drive

Tags: 14.04, drive

So I have a second internal drive that I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto but it already has data on it that I don't want to mess with. How can I go about installing without affecting this data?

Comment: Is first drive booting with BIOS(MBR) or UEFI (gpt). And then is second drive using the same type of partitioning MBR(msdos) or gpt. Be sure to use Something Else and install grub2's boot loader to second drive not sda. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Answer (score 1):

Move the files someplace else and then install Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That was always in my mind but I don't have a hard drive that big that can store those files. Isn't there a way to create a secondary partition on the existing hard drive? If so, what filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do what you want. Burn Ubuntu to a CD or USB drive and then boot from it. On the first screen, select `Try Ubuntu`. Open Unity Dash by clicking the Ubuntu logo at the top of the launcher and search `Gparted`. Here you can partition the other drive. You can just leave the free space as free space; the setup program will be able to format it correctly. Once you're done partitioning (don't forget to hit Apply) close Gparted and open the setup program again (second icon in the launcher). When you hit the screen where the setup asks where you want to install Ubuntu, select `Something Else` and select the free space you made. I'll add formatting to this if it makes it easier to follow.

Comment: By free space, do you mean unallocated space? If I try to partition the unallocated space, it asks for free space preceding, new size, and free space following. Which do I enter in the values for? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't worry about it; just click OK.